# How to count the number of segments in a string in r?

Tags: r, regex, string, count

I have a string printed out like this:

```
"\"Jenna and Alex were making cupcakes.\", \"Jenna asked Alex whether all were ready to be frosted.\", \"Alex said that\", \" some of them \", \"were.\", \"He added\", \"that\", \"the rest\", \"would be\", \"ready\", \"soon.\", \"\""
```

(The "\" wasn't there. R just automatically prints it out.)

I would like to calculate how many non-empty segments there are in this string. In this case the answer should be 11.

I tried to convert it to a vector, but R ignores the quotation marks so I still ended up with a vector with length 1.

I don't know whether I need to extract those segments first and then count, or there're easier ways to do that.

If it's the former case, which regular expression function best suits my need?

Thank you very much.

Comment: would you share your data with `dput`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `scan` to convert your large string into a vector of individual ones, then use `nchar` to count the lengths. Assuming your large string is `x`:

```
y <- scan(text=x, what="character", sep=",", strip.white=TRUE)
Read 12 items
sum(nchar(y)>0)
[1] 11
```

Answer (score 0):

`strsplit` might be one possibility?

```
txt <-  "Jenna and Alex were making cupcakes., Jenna asked Alex whether all were ready to be frosted.,
Alex said that,  some of them , were., He added, that, the rest, would be, ready, soon.,"

a <- strsplit(txt, split=",")


length(a[[1]])
[1] 11
```

If the backslashes are part of the text it doesnt really change a lot, except for the last element which would have `"\""` in it. By filtering that out, the result is the same:

```
txt <- "\"Jenna and Alex were making cupcakes.\", \"Jenna asked Alex whether all 
were ready to be frosted.\", \"Alex said that\", \" some of them \", 
\"were.\", \"He added\", \"that\", \"the rest\", \"would be\", \"ready\", \"soon.\", \"\""

a <- strsplit(txt, split=", \"")

length(a[[1]][a[[1]] != "\""])
[1] 11
```

Comment: I interpreted the statement "The '\' wasn't there" to imply that when printed via `cat`, the backslashes weren't present.  Otherwise, it seems the quotes are part of the string.  I'm not sure your `txt` object matches what is described in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I assume a segment is defined as anything between `.` or `,`. An option using `strsplit` can be found as:

```
length(grep("\\w+", trimws(strsplit(str, split=",|\\.")[[1]])))
#[1] 11
```

**Note:**  `trimws` is not mandatory in above statement. I have included so that one can get the value of each segment by just adding `value = TRUE` argument in `grep`.

**Data:**

```
str <- "\"Jenna and Alex were making cupcakes.\", \"Jenna asked Alex whether all were ready to be frosted.\", \"Alex said that\", \" some of them \", \"were.\", \"He added\", \"that\", \"the rest\", \"would be\", \"ready\", \"soon.\", \"\""
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an absurd idea, but it does work:

```
txt <- "\"Jenna and Alex were making cupcakes.\", \"Jenna asked Alex whether all were ready to be frosted.\", \"Alex said that\", \" some of them \", \"were.\", \"He added\", \"that\", \"the rest\", \"would be\", \"ready\", \"soon.\", \"\""

Txt <- 
  read.csv(text = txt,
           header = FALSE,
           colClasses = "character",
           na.strings = c("", " "))

sum(!vapply(Txt, is.na, logical(1)))
```

Comment: That sums up to 12.   With this `sum(!vapply(Txt[!Txt == " "], is.na, logical(1)))` it sums up to 11, as desired.

Comment: You're right.  After switching to using the `colClasses` argument, I had to do some work on identifying `NA`s. Thanks for catching that.